# WebDriverException: Message: 'Can not connect to the ChromeDriver'

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

Trying to use run a test with selenium and Chrome I've got this error:

```
$ python3.4 /var/lib/jenkins/scripts/testlink/pacote_deslogado.py
while not utils.is_connectable(self.port): /usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/chrome/service.py:70: ResourceWarning: unclosed <socket.socket fd=7, family=AddressFamily.AF_INET, type=2049, proto=0, laddr=('127.0.0.1', 54866)>

======================================================================
ERROR: test_a_h_nacional_deslogado (__main__.AHNacionalDeslogado)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/var/lib/jenkins/scripts/testlink/pacote_deslogado.py", line 25, in setUp
self.driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='/usr/bin/chromedriver')
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/chrome/webdriver.py", line 59, in __init__
self.service.start()
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/chrome/service.py", line 74, in start
raise WebDriverException("Can not connect to the ChromeDriver")
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Can not connect to the ChromeDriver
```

I have Chromedrive avaliable in my PATH and it is executable, I installed Chromium-Browser.

I don't know what else I can do.

Comment: What is the output of  `which chromedriver`? Thanks.

Comment: Chromedriver 2.14, Selenium 2.44.

Comment: In that line is just the "webdriver.Chrome()"

Answer (score 0):

the same error with phantomjs.
I solved it by edit the path of phantojs;
the path is nonstandard before :)